# Data loss when sorting points

Tags: python

After finding a large set of points I'm now trying to sort them such that:

```
arr = [(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(2,1)(2,3)]
```

becomes:

```
[[(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)],[(2,1)(2,3)]]
```

In other words I'm trying to group the points by their x coordinate.

I wrote below function to do this:

```
def sortPoints(points):
    prev = NULL
    sorted = []
    groupe = []
    for p in points:
        if prev == NULL : prev = p[0]
        if p[0] == prev:
            groupe.append(p)
        else :
            sorted.append(groupe[:])
            del groupe[:]
            prev = p[0]
    return sorted
```

When I run the code I get an array with sorted points as expected, however, a large part of the points also vanish in the process, and I cannot figure out why.

If anyone could help me, that would be great and very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using `itertools.groupby`? Also, you need to consider the last `groupe` after the for loop has ended.

Comment: And where is `NULL` defined?

Comment: Also, you are missing some commas in your lists.

Comment: `sorted` is a reserved keyword in python. I suggest you change the variable name from `sorted` to something else. And are you sure that the given array will be ordered in a way that x-coordinate will be consecutive only? [`groupby`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/itertools-groupby-in-python/) has similar example with explanation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might want to show what is "missing". If the original list you are providing is not sorted, it will not group it properly as it is. Note that if you never get a different value of p[0], the accumulated list groupe is never added to your final list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mark suggested you should use `itertools.groupby` for such cases

```
from itertools import groupby
arr = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,3)]
arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
[list(v) for _,v in groupby(arr, lambda y: y[0])]
# output
[[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], [(2, 1), (2, 3)]]
```

Comment: For @Fnoefen: please note that the list must be sorted before using `groupby` to see the expected result.